# <noscript> in <head>

Tags: html, xhtml

Am I allowed to place `<noscript>` in the `<head>`?

Comment: I wonder what you will put there... Beside changing title or CSS, the options are limited.

Comment: I found this question because my <noscript> in the <head> was failing HTML validation.  I use it to do a 'meta refresh' and take the Javascript-less user to a different webpage which asks them to enable JS.  Seems to work in the browsers I've tried, but the validator hates it, as Greg pointed out that it should... still, if it's working... I'm leaving it for now.

Comment: In HTML5 it seems the same

Comment: I believe this is an excellent question because most analytics code contains the noscript tag but fails to inform the user that it must be injected separately from the head.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the [XHTML Strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd), no, you're allowed script, style, meta, link, object, title and base only.  Transitional allows isindex as well, but still not noscript.

Answer (score 21):

Using the HTML5 Doctype, I have a  declaration in my `<head>` with a `<link>` element that points to a no-js.css stylesheet. It validates and seems to work fine.

Comment: According to the current working draft, `<head>` [may contain any metadata elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-head-element) with `<noscript>` being [defined as one](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#metadata-content).

Comment: So it is valid. Thanks for the clarification musikK. This might be a better approach instead of a "no-js" / "js" class for the HTML element for preventing a flicker

Comment: Just to keep up with the times and now that everything is going HTML5, perhaps this should now be the accepted answer.  With advice to pay attention to Greg's answer if users need older support.

Comment: @T.Todua I cannot update the comment but there is a single page version of the document: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html. [Way to go W3C, way to go.](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI)

Answer (score 1):

You are as long as you do it in HTML documents and not XHTML.

> In a head element [...], the noscript element must contain only link,
>   style, and meta elements.

[See specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element).

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 adds support to `<noscript>` in the `<head>`: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Answer (score 0):

Found this while searching for a similar thing, thought I'd provide a 2023 update.

As part of the [HTML5 W3C spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-noscript-element), you can place a `<noscript>` tag within the `<head>`.

> *"In a head element of an HTML document, if there are no ancestor noscript elements."*