# Facebook scraper closes the head tag on my page when it finds a <noscript> tag

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, head, noscript

When the Facebook scraper looks at my page it closes the head tag when it finds a noscript tag. If you view the page source you will see that the meta tags are within the head tag of the page. Look at the debugger for the error: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rightmove.co.uk%2Fproperty-for-sale%2Fproperty-34534103.html

On the Facebook open graph debugger you get a different page that has closed the head tag early: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rightmove.co.uk%2Fproperty-for-sale%2Fproperty-34534103.html

Strange ehy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<noscript>` tag wouldn't be valid in a `<head>` element would it? Maybe Facebook's parser is considering the presence of the noscript tag to be implicitly ending the `<head>`?

See here also: [<noscript> in <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252891/noscript-in-head)

Comment: That must mean that the scaper validated the page as Strict XHTML, even though the DOCTYPE was not set to strict?

Comment: I don't think transitional allows noscript tags there either, does it?

Comment: A <noscript> tag in the head IS valid HTML5 - http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-noscript-element.html